# Formatting sorted data

Tags: format, output

I have written the following code:

```
public void sortLastName() {

    ObjectList sortedList = new ObjectList();

    ObjectListNode p = database.getFirstNode();

    while (p != null) {

        Employee emp = (Employee) database.removeFirst();

        sortedList.insert(emp);

        p = database.getFirstNode();

    }

    database = sortedList.copyList();

    System.out.println("\nThe database, sorted by last name, is: ");

    pw.write("\nThe database, sorted by last name, is: \n");

    outputHeader();

    printSortedData();

}
```

Now, when I compile this code (along with all the other code that goes along with it, the output looks nothing like what I want.  Is there any way to use printSotedData() while formatting the output a certain way.  Am I missing something extraordinarily simple?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I answered your question please remember to choose a best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `printf()` function like this

`System.out.printf(string, variables)`

It is the print with formatting function similar to the one in C. It is a function with variable arguments, meaning it can take many different inputs. Internally it is not implemented as an overloaded function. Lets say you wanted to print numbers in a table with each row containing 5 items assuming I had 25 numbers or something like that.

```
//Assuming data is an array of 20 numbers
for(x = data.length - 5; x > 0; x = x - 5){
System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n", data[x], data[x+1], data[x+2], data[x+3], data[x+4]
}
```

This would create output that looked like this:

```
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
```

The string that you pass into it contains string modifiers, which are placeholders so you can worry about formatting. `\t` is the ASCII character for a tab. There is also `\n` for a new line. There is a whole table but these are the most useful. There are also several other string modifiers you can use. You will find a table [here](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm). For the specific problem that you are asking about, your string modifier will look very similar to the one I posted above assuming you have multiple bits of info that needs to be separated. Remember to add a new line character at the end or you will not move down to the next line. Unlinke println() it does not "print a new line" it only prints what you tell it to. This may seem weird at first but it allows you to have complete control of formatting.

Also as an aside, println() is equivalent to this:

```
   String x = "important words";
   System.out.printf("%s\n", x); == System.out.println(x);
```

both will print:

`important words`

`println()` is a shortcut function because printing a string on a line is such a common task.